# How to change Matlab's scaling process when not Native?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to change the downsampling method or the process by which Matlab changes picture when resolution is not native. 
I am especially interested in the scaling methods which are suitable for scientific computing in grayscale. 
Default Matlab 2016a's warning whatever the scaling is

> Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 50%.

Either the scaling is 10^-6 or 1/2, my Matlab 2016a always says that it is 50%, which is irritating.

---

How can you change Matlab's downsampling method or corresponding scaling process?

Comment: What do you mean? If you're talking about how big an image is displayed, it depends upon the size of the axes and figure.

Comment: If you're talking about the warning issued by `imshow`, This is because you are trying to display something that is *bigger* (more pixels) than you monitor therefore it zooms out to show it all.

Comment: @Suever My friend of signal processing tells me that there are ways/processes which you can decide how to do it. Averaging/random/stochastic/... Significant differences in results. Default way, he says, is poor in Matlab. I want to test many ways.

Comment: you would have to implement those downsampling methods yourself as they are not part of `imshow`

Comment: @Suever Yes, it is called downsampling. My friend says that there exists downsampling method default in Matlab. I run `imshow` in Matlab 2016a. It does it default downsampling. How can you study the method?

Comment: @Masi just resize the image before showing I guess. `imresize` allows to do that and choose a method. Still.... This is for displaying pourposes, so you probbly wont notice the difference in bare eye. Resampling methods are relevant when you do maths with the result, but not that relevnt to see the image on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When displaying an image you should use [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html).
In `imshow` you can set the zoom level.
Look at the `ImshowInitialMagnification` property of `imshow`.

For instant:

```
mInputImage = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(mInputImage, 'ImshowInitialMagnification', 100);
```

Comment: Actually, I am doing right this one at the moment but you still can get 50% scalling by "this" method.

Comment: Well, it means you're trying to display image which is bigger than your screen resolution.

Comment: Yes, it only means that the image is bigger than your screen resolution. The value 50% is very rough estimate. Matlab offer 50% or 33% even if the scaling is much much bigger.